# Celery workers get stuck at acquire (logging.py/__init__)

Tags: python, logging, thread-safety, celery

Any help related to this would be appreciated and will be really helpful to us.

Celery version - 5.2.7

broker - rabbitmq

Django version - 3.2.7

**ISSUE -**

Celery workers hang every time after processing some random no of tasks.
For every time celery hangs we need to manually stop the celery process and restart it.

Command to run celery -

```
celery -A APP_NAME worker -l info -c 8 -P threads -Q main_server_queue,document_queue --without-gossip
```

**Debugging -**

At the first, we monitored rabbitmq when celery hangs, it works fine.
But it shows zero consumers once celery process hangs.

Next, we tried linux strace cmd on celery pid to check where it hangs on the system level.

```
sudo strace -p 7233
Output -->
strace: Process 7233 attached
futex(0x55b4670b0d80, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, NULL, ffffffff
```

**every time celery workers stuck, strace shows the same futex function call

To get the debug output in the pythonic way we used py-spy library. To check at which point in the code it hangs.

Used the following command to get a dump of workers/threads -

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" py-spy dump --pid 7233
```

There was total 8 threads. As we are using threads based execution pool so each thread is a celery worker.
Output shows methods traced from recent to oldest (top to bottom).

As we can see all the threads stuck at acquire method of python logging module.

Some of these log calls are made by the libraries we use, so we have little to no control over those logs.

Output of the command -

```
Thread 7233 (idle): "MainThread"
    poll (kombu/utils/eventio.py:81)
    create_loop (kombu/asynchronous/hub.py:306)
    asynloop (celery/worker/loops.py:97)
    start (celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:628)
    start (celery/bootsteps.py:116)
    start (celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:332)
    start (celery/bootsteps.py:365)
    start (celery/bootsteps.py:116)
    start (celery/worker/worker.py:203)
    worker (celery/bin/worker.py:351)
    caller (celery/bin/base.py:134)
    new_func (click/decorators.py:26)
    invoke (click/core.py:760)
    invoke (click/core.py:1404)
    invoke (click/core.py:1657)
    main (click/core.py:1055)
    __call__ (click/core.py:1130)
    main (celery/bin/celery.py:217)
    main (celery/__main__.py:15)
    <module> (celery:8)
Thread 7468 (idle): "ThreadPoolExecutor-2_0"
    acquire (logging/__init__.py:903)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:952)
    callHandlers (logging/__init__.py:1661)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:1599)
    _log (logging/__init__.py:1589)
    log (logging/__init__.py:1512)
    write (celery/utils/log.py:232)
    emit (logging/__init__.py:1088)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:954)
    callHandlers (logging/__init__.py:1661)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:1599)
    _log (logging/__init__.py:1589)
    info (logging/__init__.py:1446)
    select_device (utils/torch_utils.py:80)
    detect (pipeline_signature_detect.py:65)
    process_cheque (pipeline.py:145)
    process_task (main.py:18)
    celery_cheque_task (main.py:45)
    __protected_call__ (celery/app/trace.py:734)
    trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:451)
    fast_trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:649)
    apply_target (celery/concurrency/base.py:29)
    run (concurrent/futures/thread.py:57)
    _worker (concurrent/futures/thread.py:80)
    run (threading.py:870)
    _bootstrap_inner (threading.py:932)
    _bootstrap (threading.py:890)
Thread 7469 (idle): "ThreadPoolExecutor-2_1"
    acquire (logging/__init__.py:903)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:952)
    callHandlers (logging/__init__.py:1661)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:1599)
    _log (logging/__init__.py:1589)
    log (logging/__init__.py:1512)
    write (celery/utils/log.py:232)
    detect (pipeline_signature_detect.py:166)
    process_cheque (pipeline.py:145)
    process_task (main.py:18)
    celery_cheque_task (main.py:45)
    __protected_call__ (celery/app/trace.py:734)
    trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:451)
    fast_trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:649)
    apply_target (celery/concurrency/base.py:29)
    run (concurrent/futures/thread.py:57)
    _worker (concurrent/futures/thread.py:80)
    run (threading.py:870)
    _bootstrap_inner (threading.py:932)
    _bootstrap (threading.py:890)
Thread 7470 (idle): "ThreadPoolExecutor-2_2"
    acquire (logging/__init__.py:903)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:952)
    callHandlers (logging/__init__.py:1661)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:1599)
    _log (logging/__init__.py:1589)
    log (logging/__init__.py:1512)
    write (celery/utils/log.py:232)
    predict (pipeline_predict.py:73)
    process_cheque (pipeline.py:141)
    process_task (main.py:18)
    celery_cheque_task (main.py:45)
    __protected_call__ (celery/app/trace.py:734)
    trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:451)
    fast_trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:649)
    apply_target (celery/concurrency/base.py:29)
    run (concurrent/futures/thread.py:57)
    _worker (concurrent/futures/thread.py:80)
    run (threading.py:870)
    _bootstrap_inner (threading.py:932)
    _bootstrap (threading.py:890)
Thread 7471 (idle): "ThreadPoolExecutor-2_3"
    acquire (logging/__init__.py:903)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:952)
    callHandlers (logging/__init__.py:1661)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:1599)
    _log (logging/__init__.py:1589)
    log (logging/__init__.py:1512)
    write (celery/utils/log.py:232)
    predict (pipeline_predict.py:73)
    process_cheque (pipeline.py:141)
    process_task (main.py:18)
    celery_cheque_task (main.py:45)
    __protected_call__ (celery/app/trace.py:734)
    trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:451)
    fast_trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:649)
    apply_target (celery/concurrency/base.py:29)
    run (concurrent/futures/thread.py:57)
    _worker (concurrent/futures/thread.py:80)
    run (threading.py:870)
    _bootstrap_inner (threading.py:932)
    _bootstrap (threading.py:890)
Thread 7741 (idle): "ThreadPoolExecutor-2_4"
    acquire (logging/__init__.py:903)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:952)
    callHandlers (logging/__init__.py:1661)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:1599)
    _log (logging/__init__.py:1589)
    log (logging/__init__.py:1512)
    write (celery/utils/log.py:232)
    predict (pipeline_predict.py:73)
    process_cheque (pipeline.py:141)
    process_task (main.py:18)
    celery_cheque_task (main.py:45)
    __protected_call__ (celery/app/trace.py:734)
    trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:451)
    fast_trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:649)
    apply_target (celery/concurrency/base.py:29)
    run (concurrent/futures/thread.py:57)
    _worker (concurrent/futures/thread.py:80)
    run (threading.py:870)
    _bootstrap_inner (threading.py:932)
    _bootstrap (threading.py:890)
Thread 7742 (idle): "ThreadPoolExecutor-2_5"
    acquire (logging/__init__.py:903)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:952)
    callHandlers (logging/__init__.py:1661)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:1599)
    _log (logging/__init__.py:1589)
    log (logging/__init__.py:1512)
    write (celery/utils/log.py:232)
    predict (pipeline_predict.py:73)
    process_cheque (pipeline.py:141)
    process_task (main.py:18)
    celery_cheque_task (main.py:45)
    __protected_call__ (celery/app/trace.py:734)
    trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:451)
    fast_trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:649)
    apply_target (celery/concurrency/base.py:29)
    run (concurrent/futures/thread.py:57)
    _worker (concurrent/futures/thread.py:80)
    run (threading.py:870)
    _bootstrap_inner (threading.py:932)
    _bootstrap (threading.py:890)
Thread 7760 (idle): "ThreadPoolExecutor-2_6"
    acquire (logging/__init__.py:903)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:952)
    callHandlers (logging/__init__.py:1661)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:1599)
    _log (logging/__init__.py:1589)
    log (logging/__init__.py:1512)
    write (celery/utils/log.py:232)
    detect (pipeline_signature_detect.py:166)
    process_cheque (pipeline.py:145)
    process_task (main.py:18)
    celery_cheque_task (main.py:45)
    __protected_call__ (celery/app/trace.py:734)
    trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:451)
    fast_trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:649)
    apply_target (celery/concurrency/base.py:29)
    run (concurrent/futures/thread.py:57)
    _worker (concurrent/futures/thread.py:80)
    run (threading.py:870)
    _bootstrap_inner (threading.py:932)
    _bootstrap (threading.py:890)
Thread 7761 (idle): "ThreadPoolExecutor-2_7"
    acquire (logging/__init__.py:903)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:952)
    callHandlers (logging/__init__.py:1661)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:1599)
    _log (logging/__init__.py:1589)
    log (logging/__init__.py:1512)
    write (celery/utils/log.py:232)
    emit (logging/__init__.py:1088)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:954)
    callHandlers (logging/__init__.py:1661)
    handle (logging/__init__.py:1599)
    _log (logging/__init__.py:1589)
    info (logging/__init__.py:1446)
    select_device (utils/torch_utils.py:80)
    detect (pipeline_signature_detect.py:65)
    process_cheque (pipeline.py:145)
    process_task (main.py:18)
    celery_cheque_task (main.py:45)
    __protected_call__ (celery/app/trace.py:734)
    trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:451)
    fast_trace_task (celery/app/trace.py:649)
    apply_target (celery/concurrency/base.py:29)
    run (concurrent/futures/thread.py:57)
    _worker (concurrent/futures/thread.py:80)
    run (threading.py:870)
    _bootstrap_inner (threading.py:932)
    _bootstrap (threading.py:890)
```

We think the issue might be related to the python logging module locks, so we tried running celery without `-l info` flag

```
celery -A APP_NAME worker -c 8 -P threads -Q main_server_queue,document_queue --without-gossip
```

Now celery workers hang less often as compared to before, but still they stuck at acquire (`logging/__init__.py:903`)

We are certain that issue is related with logging locks as strace shows futex which has to do with locks.

Comment: Can you share information about how logging is configured? Specific handlers used? Also, does anything do reconfiguration of logging while workers are running?

Comment: @VinaySajip We haven't configured the logging in our code. We have print statements in the code that celery considers as logs inside its execution pool and call its internal log setup for those print statements. Libraries that we have added, have logging configured, but we don't have control over that. The handler that gets passed to acquire as a self is StreamHandler. Checked it using py-spy as it also shows parameters and locals of function.  `acquire (logging/__init__.py:903)
        Arguments:
            self: <StreamHandler at 0x7ff00c4b8820>
    handle (logging/__init__.py:952) `

Comment: Logging should be done by your application, not by any libraries. I'd advise finding out where that `StreamHandler` is configured.